# Initializing object with array of self-type as internal property: infinite initialization?

Tags: c#

my question is basically about the manner in which C# initializes arrays.

Specifically, I am creating a large tree data structure to store words in `C#`. A subclass of this data structure, created as `node` objects, has two fields: `int value` and `node[] nexts`.

Wouldn't initializing a `node` object, as below, create an infinite initialization loop when `this.nexts = new node[26]` is called?

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a node object for a letter.
/// </summary>
private class node {
    public int value;
    internal node[] nexts;
    public node(bool z, int n = 0, node[] ns = null) {
        this.value = n;
        if (z) {
            if (ns == null) { this.nexts = new node[26]; }
            else { this.nexts = ns; }
        }
    }
}
```

If not and this is the correct way to initialize an object with a property being an array of itself, in what state would each element of that array exist after initialization?

Here is the entirety of the class if you're interested:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a node object for a letter.
/// </summary>
private class node {
    public int value;
    internal node[] nexts;
    public node(bool z, int n = 0, node[] ns = null) {
        this.value = n;
        if (z) {
            if (ns == null) { this.nexts = new node[26]; }
            else { this.nexts = ns; }
        }
    }
    public node operator++(node n) {
        n.value++;
        return n;
    }
    public node this[int i] {
        get {
            if (this.nexts == null) { this.nexts = new node[26]; }
            return this.nexts[i];
        }
        set {
            if (this.nexts == null) { this.nexts = new node[26]; }
            this.nexts[i] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to know if it results in infinite recursion, run the code that you've already written.  You'll find out in a fraction of a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Wouldn't initializing a node object, as below, create an infinite initialization loop when `this.nexts = new node[26]` is called?

No, because since `node` is a *reference type*, `new node[26]` just creates an array that can hold up to 26 `node` references; it does not create any `node` objects itself.

> If not and this is the correct way to initialize an object with a property being an array of itself, in what state would each element of that array exist after initialization?

Each element of the array will contain a `null` reference.

Comment: Thank you, that clears things up! Maybe that property of a `struct` could be useful...

Comment: "If node were a struct, then it would create an infinite recursion." No, it wouldn't.

Comment: Would be good to fix that indeed. It won't create infinite recursion in this case , nor can you make it to cause infinite recursion somehow with struct, since struct cannot have explicit construcor.

Comment: @Dennis_E Thanks, fixed.

Comment: @Evk Explicit *parameterless* constructor.